# Google Apps Script コード画面の無限ロードに関して

Tags: google-apps-script

GASプログラムを最近始めた者です。21/11/9に突然、スクリプトエディタ内のコード部分にロードマークが現れ、コードが表示されなくなってしまいました。いままでspreadsheet→スクリプトエディタにてコード画面を開いており、ネット上にあった、異なる現象（ファイルが開けない、権限がないなど）対応策もいくつか試してみましたが、一向に改善されません。また、いくら待っても応答なしやエラーなどは表示されずエラー？の検討もできておりません。

以前のバージョンよりコードだけは救出いたしましたが、実行は不可能な状態です。googleの不具合や更新なども11月には起きていないようですが、同様の現象が起きている方や解決した方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただければと思います。よろしくお願い致します。

**試したこと**

- すべてのアカウントからログアウト
- 別のブラウザの利用(普段利用:Google Chrome、検証ブラウザ:IE)
- キャッシュの削除（全期間）
- Google Chrome右上のアカウント同期及び削除
- 他PC端末の利用
- PCの再起動
- 別spreadsheetを作成（同様の現象が起きます。このとき最初は、画面全体は灰色で上部に青色のバーが行ったり来たりしている状態。このまま待っても特に何も起きないため、ページロードをかけると、コード部分にロードマークが現れるという状態となる）
- 組織PC（上記を行った）ものに、組織外のアカウントを利用しても同様の現象が見られた。
- （予定）組織外の自機PCにて、組織外アカウントを利用し、同様の現象が起きるかの検証。

**11/12追記**

所属している組織でも同様の現象が確認できたため、googleに問い合わせ中との連絡がありました。原因が判明次第、再度追記致します。

Comment: 最初に、明確な解決方法を提案することができず申し訳ありません。例えば、新たにSpreadsheetを作成してからスクリプトエディタを開くとどのようになるでしょうか。あるいは、そのSpreadsheetをコピーしてからスクリプトエディタを開くとどのようになるでしょうか。既にこれらを試されていた場合は謝罪致します。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
新たに作成したspreadsheetにおいても同様の現象が起きます。またこのとき最初は、画面全体は灰色で上部に青色のバーが行ったり来たりしている状態になっています。このまま待っても特に何も起きないため、ページロードをかけると、上記しているようなコード部分にロードマークが現れるという状態です。
記載がされておらず申し訳ございませんでした、追記させていただきます。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。お役に立てず申し訳ありません。あと確認することは、例えば、ブラウザでGoogle Apps Scriptのエディタに関するプラグインを使用されていたりしますでしょうか。もしも使用されているようですと、一度それらを解除してからブラウザを再起動して再度試してみるのはいかがでしょうか。プラグインが邪魔をしていてスクリプトエディタが開かないといった問題を思い出しましたのでお聞きさせていただきました。もしもそれも既に試しておられるようですと、再度謝罪致します。

Comment: 度々のコメントありがとうございます。プラグインに関しても確認しましたが、やはりありませんでした。同一の組織内で複数人同様の現象が見られたため、アカウントに問題がある可能性が示唆されましたので引き続き調査します。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。お役に立てず申し訳ありません。`同一の組織内で複数人同様の現象が見られた`について、例えば、組織外の個人のアカウントで同じブラウザでテストをしても同様の問題はありますか？本件、もしも原因が分かり、解決することができましたら、回答として投稿していただきますと、同様の問題をかかえる他のユーザにも役立つと思われます。

Comment: 組織のPCにて外部アカウントを使用した場合も同様の現象が見られました。あとは帰宅後に自機にて同様の状態となる場合はgoogle側の問題である可能性が考えられますね。解決へ導いて下さるようなご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 外部でのテスト結果を含めてGoogle Issue Trackerへ報告してはいかがでしょうか。今のところIssue Trackerを見てみましたが、同様の問題を見つけることはできませんでした。https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker

Comment: ありがとうございます。組織アカウントでは開くことができなかったため、外部アカウントを利用し、報告させていただければと思います。